# control jenkins build from java

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job that runs a java application using the exec-maven-plugin *exec:java* goal. What i would like is to control the outcome of the build from this java application. Specifically, I would like to mark the build as unstable based on some logic in the java code. Something like this

```
if (tests.failed()) {
   jenkins.markUnstable();
}
```

I know of the jenkins-cli jar but i don't want to start a process to run the jar when I know that jenkins is written in java and that there is probably an api to do something like this. I imagine even the jenkins-cli is using this same api I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? the tests are not unit tests, they are custom validations for some build artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, there is no such function in [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). The proper way to do it is to integrate your application as a test in Jenkins (unit or performance). The application should generate an xml report that can be used by Jenkins to decide if it fails or succeeds and depending on the result stop (or fail) a build.

Comment: i see. bummer.  
any guidelines on how to do your suggestion? i can generate an XML in the junit format or whatever, but after that, how do i tell jenkins to take this and process it to decide the fate of the build?

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution but I'll use [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) to parse junit (xml) or jmeter (jtl) output. I'll modify the application to generate such output/file in junit or jmeter format. The generated file can be very simple. _Performance threshold_ option in the plugin should be used to decide when a build is marked as unstable or failed.